# How to get a new array of custom object from another array using stream?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code using loop (buildAttrib1() method) to construct an array of objects with arrays inside the object.

```
public class AttribVal {
    private String value;
    // getters and setters omitted
}

public class Attrib {
    private String name;
    private AttribVal[] values; // array

    public Attrib() {
    }

    public Attrib(String name, AttribVal[] values) {
        this.name = name;
        this.values = values;
    }
    // getters and setters omitted
}

public class MyClass {
    private Attrib[] buildAttrib1(Object obj) {  // loop version
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        
        List<Attrib> attribs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            String methodName = "get"+StringUtils.capitalize(f.getName());
            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String val = (String) method.invoke(requestObject);
                attribs.add(new Attrib(f.getName(), new AttribVal[]{new AttribVal(val)}));  // AttribVal array
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        return attribs.toArray(new Attrib[attribs.size()]);
    }
    
    private Attrib[] buildAttrib2(Object obj) {  // stream version
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        
        return Arrays.stream(fields).map(f -> {
            String methodName = "get"+StringUtils.capitalize(f.getName());
            Method method = null;
            Attrib attrib = null;
            try {
                method = requestObject.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String val = (String) method.invoke(requestObject);
                attrib = new Attrib(f.getName(), new AttribVal[]{new AttribVal(val)});
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return attrib;
        }).toArray(Attrib[]::new);
    }
}
```

I converted the loop to stream (buildAttrib2() method) and it works, but it seems to me there is not much difference from the loop version. Could anyone tell me how to improve it?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Which miracle did you expect when converting a loop to a Stream operation? Note that `attribs.toArray(new Attrib[0])` [is more efficient than](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) `attribs.toArray(new Attrib[attribs.size()])`, so your Stream operation has already one benefit: you don’t need to think about such things (and it doesn’t need an intermediate storage in the first place). Note that there’s multi-catch, `catch(IllegalAccessException|InvocationTargetException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` which can simplify both variants.

Comment: @Holger, thank you for the advice.